# Switch isn't doing as commanded

Tags: java

Basically, I tried using switch but when I run it, it doesn't do the System.out.println I made. It compiles without a problem. I'm not very good at programming so please explain your answer.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MrCoffee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a;
        char d = 'y';
        Scanner mock = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi, I am Mr.Coffee what is your name?");
        a = mock.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Thank you " + a + ".");
        System.out.println(a + ", do you have a validate rewards card currrently with you?");
        String b = ("y"), c = ("n");
        System.out.println("If yes enter the letter y. If no, please enter the letter n.");
        d = mock.next().charAt(0);
        if (d == 'y') {
            Scanner low = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ok, " + a + " please enter the amount of coffee you have bought today.");
            int coffeeam, none, one, two, three, value = 1, value2 = 4;
            coffeeam = low.nextInt();
            double total = coffeeam * 2.85;
            String start = ("Thank you Alexander, you will recieve"), rat = ("The total due amount is");
            none = coffeeam / 20;
            switch (none) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Unfortunately " + a + ", this is not enough to recieve any free coffee.");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Unfortunately " + a + ", this is not enough to recieve any free coffee.");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Unfortunately " + a + ", this is not enough to recieve any free coffee.");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Unfortunately " + a + ", this is not enough to recieve any free coffee.");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(start + " 1 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println(start + " 1 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println(start + " 1 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println(start + " 1 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 13:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 14:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 15:
                System.out.println(start + " 2 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 16:
                System.out.println(start + " 3 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 17:
                System.out.println(start + " 3 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 18:
                System.out.println(start + " 3 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 19:
                System.out.println(start + " 3 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            case 20:
                System.out.println(start + " 3 free coffee. " + rat + " " + total + " dollars.");
                break;
            }
        } else if (d == 'n') {
            System.out.println("Sorry " + a + ", since you do not have a rewards card. I will not be able to decide on the number of free coffee you can get.");
            System.out.println("I would reccomend that you go to speak with one of our employees to register for a card.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: give test case.

Comment: I indented your code to make it more readable (most IDEs can do it for you so you should do it yourself in the future). But lets start from the beginning. How exactly your code worked? What ware you expecting instead and why?

Comment: From your code one does not get a free coffe until he buys 100 coffes, we need you to explain what you are trying to achieve.By the way you declare a bunch of variable you never use also.

Comment: Basically, I need it to be able to display how much free coffee a person gets based on what the person inputs.1 – 4 coffees = 0 free

5 – 8 coffees = 1 free

9 – 15 coffees = 2 free

16 – 20 coffees = 3 free

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem is that since you are dividing an integer by an integer:

```
none = coffeeam / 20;
```

Then if a player puts  in any value below 20, for example coffeeam = 19, then none will be 0, since it is rounding it off to 0. Therefore you switch is not running because most of the time the value of none is 0. I don't exactly know why you are dividing it by 20, but if you could elaborate on why you divide by 20, I could provide an alternative solution in order to avoid the rounding issue of integers.

Moreover, I also want to add that your switch seems really inefficient. It is better if you assign a String variable and only run one System.out.println method, such as:

```
String message;
switch (variable) {
case 1:
  message = "Cat";
  break;
case 2:
  message = "Dog";
  break;
default:
  message = "None";
  break;
}
System.out.println(message);
```